# Is there any way to make this checkbox html structure as slide with pure css?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, checkbox

this is my first question in stackoverflow ;)

I'm using a wordpress plugin called "WooCommerce TM Extra Product Options".
When I create options for any woocommerce product with checkboxes, the html that the plugin generates is exactly like the below (and the checkbox have the default appearance):

```html
    <label for="tmcp_choice_0_0_1_1519167210">
    <input class="tmcp-field ingredientepizza tmhexcolor_0_0_1_1519167210 tm-epo-field tmcp-checkbox" name="tmcp_checkbox_0_0_1519167210" data-limit="" data-exactlimit="" data-minimumlimit="" data-image="" data-imagec="" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" data-image-variations="[]" data-price="" data-rules="[&quot;&quot;]" data-original-rules="[&quot;&quot;]" data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]" value=" molho de tomate_0" id="tmcp_choice_0_0_1_1519167210" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
 <span for="tmcp_choice_0_0_1_1519167210"></span><span class="tc-label tm-label"> molho de tomate</span></label>
```

Is there any way to make a change in the following codepen CSS code (https://codepen.io/macbobbitt_/pen/BjepPG) to work with the above specific html structure (since I can't change it).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some classname rather than directly apply on global

```js
$(function() {
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).parent().addClass("active");
   } else {
     $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
   }
})
  
});
```

```css
/* for the lazy */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sanchez);

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  transition: 400ms all ease-in-out 50ms;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


html,body{ font-family: 'Sanchez', serif;}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

/*Button is :CHECKED*/

.toggle-container.active {
  background: rgba(73,168,68,1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(73,168,68,1);
}

.toggle-container.active span:not(.tc-label) {
  left: 110px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}


/*shared*/

label,
span:not(.tc-label) {
  border-radius: 50px;
}


/*'un':checked state*/

label {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(43,43,43,1);
  text-align: center;
}
label .tc-label {
  bottom: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
}

span:not(.tc-label) {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:not(.tc-label)::before {
  content: '';
  height: 60px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

span:not(.tc-label)::after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

span:not(.tc-label)::before,
span:not(.tc-label)::after{
  background: rgba(43,43,43,1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* pesduo class on toggle */

.toggle-container.active span:not(.tc-label)::before{
  height: 50px;
  top: calc(55% - 25px);
  background: rgba(73,168,68,1);
}
.toggle-container.active span:not(.tc-label)::after{
  width: 20px;
  top: calc(95% - 25px);
  background: rgba(73,168,68,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <label for="tmcp_choice_0_0_1_1519167210" class="toggle-container">
        <input class="tmcp-field ingredientepizza tmhexcolor_0_0_1_1519167210 tm-epo-field tmcp-checkbox" name="tmcp_checkbox_0_0_1519167210" data-limit="" data-exactlimit="" data-minimumlimit="" data-image="" data-imagec="" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" data-image-variations="[]" data-price="" data-rules="[&quot;&quot;]" data-original-rules="[&quot;&quot;]" data-rulestype="[&quot;&quot;]" value=" molho de tomate_0" id="tmcp_choice_0_0_1_1519167210" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
     <span for="tmcp_choice_0_0_1_1519167210"></span><span class="tc-label tm-label"> molho de tomate</span></label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kasnady (I marked it useful but as I am new at the site, my vote doesn't count/appear before I reach level 15).
I'm able to add a class in the checkbox element (in this case, I added the class "ingredientepizza"). I can add a class too in a parent div.
Is there any solution only with CSS (without js)?